# Плагин в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Раньше работала в Visual Studio, но теперь перешла на Visual Studio Code. В Visual Studio была такая функция что при нажатии на ctrl и нажатием мышки на модуль или функцию в другой вкладке открывался исходный код этого модуля/функции. По умолчанию в Visual Studio Code нет такой функциональности. Можете подсказать плагин который позволит это сделать))

Comment: Для каждого языка программирования свой плагин по сути это реализует, причем проект нужно как папку открывать (через open folder).

Comment: C# и java, JavaScript, Typescript та же кобинация. Вам какой язык?

Comment: мне нужно для python

Answer (score 0):

Установите https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python
Это исходники. Выполните инструкции по установке и создайте простой проект. Далее

Go to Definition  <kbd>F12</kbd>

Peek Definition <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>